# Access data from web.config in InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-config

I want to access the URL from `web.config` file in sharepoint 2013. I have written the following code :

```
string siteUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strSharepointURL"] + "/Admin/";
```

but it returns null value to me.

The following is the block from the `web.config` file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=20" />
    <add key="strSharepointURL" value="http://mansi:2604/" />
    <add key="siteURL" value="http://mansi:2604/Admin" />
    <add key="adminSiteURL" value="http://mansi:2604/Admin" />
   </appSettings>
```

What is incorrect in my code? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say, without seeing an example of your web.config entry.  It looks like you are using c# and asp.net (which would use its own web.config).  You might be making a web part (which would be different rules).  Try using this:

```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1"))
   {
       System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", site.WebApplication.Name);
       AppSettingsSection appSettings = config.AppSettings;
       return appSettings.ElementInformation.IsPresent;
   }
```

I got this code from a discussion on MSDN: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8af0fc9a-fba3-4d1e-8dd4-12a46da561e8/c-programmatically-read-the-webconfig-file-of-sharepoint-site

Comment: Please refer my edited question for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry to say but @TimG, the code you mentioned does not work for me!! Please guide me with some other code.

Comment: Your tags say you are using Infopath? Infopath doesn't use web.config files but it can call web services. What are you putting this code in? A web part or aspx (asp.net) or web service (or something else)?  Are you trying to use infopath .net extensions to get a url from SharePoint's web.config?

Comment: Yes @TimG, you understood it right. I am accessing the URL of my site collection from the web.config file of the web application and for that purpose I have written this code.

Comment: It might be easier to store the URL(s) of your site as XML, checked into SharePoint (as an ordinary XML file). InfoPath reads XML files so easily. Putting them into a web.config and using InfoPath to hit a WCF to read it from a web.config seems like a few extra (unnecessary) steps. It adds complexity without adding value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Where have you written this code?